# Finding smallest number after a certain number: Comparable smallestAfter(Comparable[] values, Comparable after)

Tags: java, algorithm, object

I am trying to write an algorithm that find the smallest number after a user define the number. Say the values = {4,2,1,3}. And the user wants to find the smallest after 2, the program would shoot out 3.

Any clues or help to what to put in the body of smallestAfter??
Thanks.
Here is what I have so far:

```
public static Comparable smallest(Comparable[] values)
{
  Comparable smallestSoFar = values[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++)
     if (values[i].compareTo(smallestSoFar) < 0)
        smallestSoFar = values[i];
  return smallestSoFar;
}   
 public static Comparable smallestAfter(Comparable[] values, Comparable after)
 {   
        //After a few help, this is my algorithm I personally wrote.
             Comparable smallest = smallest(values);
             Comparable largest = smallest(values);
             for(int i = 1; i < values.length; i ++){
                  if(largest.compareTo(values[i]) < 0){
                   largest = values[i];
                }
          }


    for(int i = 1; i < values.length; i ++){
        if((values[i].compareTo(smallest) > 0) && (values[i].compareTo(after)       > 0) && (values[i].compareTo(largest) < 0))
            smallest = values[i];
    }
    return smallest;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for each v in values {
    if (v < smallestSoFar AND v > after) {
        smallestSoFar = v;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `&&` instead of `AND`?

Answer (score 0):

You can change <, > with compareTo. Other answers would not work if there is no number bigger than 'after', and they will just return first element instead of nothing.

```
public static Comparable smallestAfter(Comparable[] values, Comparable after) {

 Comparable smallest = null;
 for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
     if (values[i] > after && (smallest == null || values[i] < smallest)) {
         smallest = values[i];
     }
 }
 return smallest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Logic:**

Loop through all the elements.

```
a) If the current element is smaller than first, then update smallest 
   and second smallest. 
b) Else if the current element is smaller than second and not the smallest element then 
   update the second smallest.
c) The logic will fail when the array size is 2. So find the smallest element by 
   comparison and store the results accordingly.
```

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int[] values={13,23,3,45,56,0};
int smallest=values[0];
int beforeSmallest=smallest;

for(int num:values){

    if(num<smallest){
        beforeSmallest=smallest;
        smallest=num;
    }

    if((num<beforeSmallest)&&(num!=smallest)){
        beforeSmallest=num;
    }
}

if(values.length==2){
    if(values[0]<values[1]){
        smallest=values[0];
        beforeSmallest=values[1];
    }else{
        smallest=values[1];
        beforeSmallest=values[0];
    }

}

System.out.println(smallest+"--> Smallest");
System.out.println(beforeSmallest+"--> Before Smallest");

}
```